# Add notification at the bottom of every page in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, notifications, erb

I have a rails application in which I show a notification at the bottom of my home page using [overhang.js](https://github.com/paulkr/overHang.js/)
I want to extend this functionality of showing this notification on all pages. I am assuming this can be done using aplication.html.erb file but I don't understand how? The body tag of my application.html.erb file is given below:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div>
        <%=yield%>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</body>
```

The script for overhang.js that exists currently on home page is given below:

```
$("body").overhang({
      type: "confirm",
      primary: "#8dc153",
      accent: "#FCE4EC",
      yesColor: "#3498DB",
      message: "Privacy policy",
      overlay: true,

      callback: function (value) {
        var response = "Okay";
        #code to handle response
      }
    });
```

I want to add this notification at the bottom of all pages of my application. How can I do that? Also, if using overhang.js for this scenario is not approapriate, kindly suggest me the correct approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the solution was quite simple. I simply had to put the overhang script from home page to application.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a div in your layout/footer partial

```
<div id="notification-element"></div>
```

and add this js script code.

```
alert($("notification-element").data("overhangConfirm"));
```

hopefully that'll do the work for you